# build error while instrumenting opentelemetry into c++ application

Tags: reference, undefined

```
root@kesharib:/home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/roll-dice/build# cmake --build .
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target dice-server
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable dice-server
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/sdk/src/trace/libopentelemetry_trace.a(tracer_provider.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::internal_log::GlobalLogHandler::GetLogHandler()':
tracer_provider.cc:(.text._ZN13opentelemetry2v13sdk6common12internal_log16GlobalLogHandler13GetLogHandlerEv[_ZN13opentelemetry2v13sdk6common12internal_log16GlobalLogHandler13GetLogHandlerEv]+0x9): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::internal_log::GlobalLogHandler::GetHandlerAndLevel()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/sdk/src/trace/libopentelemetry_trace.a(tracer_provider.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::internal_log::GlobalLogHandler::GetLogLevel()':
tracer_provider.cc:(.text._ZN13opentelemetry2v13sdk6common12internal_log16GlobalLogHandler11GetLogLevelEv[_ZN13opentelemetry2v13sdk6common12internal_log16GlobalLogHandler11GetLogLevelEv]+0x9): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::internal_log::GlobalLogHandler::GetHandlerAndLevel()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/sdk/src/trace/libopentelemetry_trace.a(random_id_generator.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::trace::RandomIdGenerator::GenerateSpanId()':
random_id_generator.cc:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::Random::GenerateRandomBuffer(opentelemetry::v1::nostd::span<unsigned char, 18446744073709551615ul>)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/sdk/src/trace/libopentelemetry_trace.a(random_id_generator.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::trace::RandomIdGenerator::GenerateTraceId()':
random_id_generator.cc:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::Random::GenerateRandomBuffer(opentelemetry::v1::nostd::span<unsigned char, 18446744073709551615ul>)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/exporters/ostream/libopentelemetry_exporter_ostream_span.a(span_exporter.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::exporter::trace::OStreamSpanExporter::OStreamSpanExporter(std::ostream&)':
span_exporter.cc:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::trace::SpanExporter::SpanExporter()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/exporters/ostream/libopentelemetry_exporter_ostream_span.a(span_exporter.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::exporter::trace::OStreamSpanExporter::~OStreamSpanExporter()':
span_exporter.cc:(.text._ZN13opentelemetry2v18exporter5trace19OStreamSpanExporterD2Ev[_ZN13opentelemetry2v18exporter5trace19OStreamSpanExporterD5Ev]+0x36): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::trace::SpanExporter::~SpanExporter()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/exporters/ostream/libopentelemetry_exporter_ostream_span.a(span_exporter.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN13opentelemetry2v18exporter5trace19OStreamSpanExporterE[_ZTIN13opentelemetry2v18exporter5trace19OStreamSpanExporterE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for opentelemetry::v1::sdk::trace::SpanExporter'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/maiya/otel-cpp-starter/opentelemetry-cpp/build/sdk/src/resource/libopentelemetry_resources.a(resource_detector.cc.o): in function `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::resource::OTELResourceDetector::Detect()':
resource_detector.cc:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::GetStringEnvironmentVariable(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
/usr/bin/ld: resource_detector.cc:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `opentelemetry::v1::sdk::common::GetStringEnvironmentVariable(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dice-server.dir/build.make:102: dice-server] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/dice-server.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

the above error am getting while instumenting the opentelemetry into one of the c++ application.

this the CMakeLists.txt

```
project(RollDiceServer)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
# Set C++ standard (e.g., C++17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(project_name roll-dice-server)

# Define your project's source files
set(SOURCES
    main.cpp  # Add your source files here
)

# Create an executable target
add_executable(dice-server ${SOURCES})

#set oatpp package path
set(OATPP_ROOT ../oatpp)

#set opentelemetry path
set(OPENTELEMETRY_ROOT ../opentelemetry-cpp)

#find the library for the oatpp
find_library(OATPP_LIB NAMES liboatpp.a HINTS "${OATPP_ROOT}/build/src/" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)


#find the opentelemetry libraries path
find_library(OPENTELEMETRY_COMMON_LIB NAMES libopentelemetry_common.a HINTS "${OPENTELEMETRY_ROOT}/build/sdk/src/common" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_library(OPENTELEMETRY_TRACE_LIB NAMES libopentelemetry_trace.a HINTS "${OPENTELEMETRY_ROOT}/build/sdk/src/trace" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_library(OPENTELEMETRY_EXPORTER_LIB NAMES libopentelemetry_exporter_ostream_span.a HINTS "${OPENTELEMETRY_ROOT}/build/exporters/ostream" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_library(OPENTELEMETRY_RESOURCE_LIB NAMES libopentelemetry_resources.a HINTS "${OPENTELEMETRY_ROOT}/build/sdk/src/resource" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)


#check whether oatpp library found
if (NOT OATPP_LIB)
  message(SEND_ERROR "Did not find oatpp library ${OATPP_ROOT}/build/src")
endif()

#set the path of oatpp to the directory containing "oatpp" package configuration files
include_directories(${OATPP_ROOT}/src)


#set the path of opentelemetry to the directory containing "opentelemetry" package configuration files
include_directories(${OPENTELEMETRY_ROOT}/api/include)
include_directories(${OPENTELEMETRY_ROOT}/sdk/include)
#include_directories(${OPENTELEMETRY_ROOT}/sdk/src)
include_directories(${OPENTELEMETRY_ROOT}/exporters/ostream/include)


#check whether opentelemetry libraries found
if(OPENTELEMETRY_COMMON_LIB AND OPENTELEMETRY_TRACE_LIB AND OPENTELEMETRY_EXPORTER_LIB AND OPENTELEMETRY_RESOURCE_LIB)
  message(STATUS "Found opentelemetry libraries")
else()
  message(SEND_ERROR "Did not find opentelemetry libraries")
endif()


#link all the necessary libraries to the final target file
#target_link_libraries(dice-server PRIVATE ${OATPP_LIB})
target_link_libraries(dice-server PRIVATE ${OATPP_LIB} ${OPENTELEMETRY_COMMON_LIB} ${OPENTELEMETRY_TRACE_LIB} ${OPENTELEMETRY_EXPORTER_LIB} ${OPENTELEMETRY_RESOURCE_LIB})
```

This is the main.cpp

```
#include "oatpp/web/server/HttpConnectionHandler.hpp"
#include "oatpp/network/Server.hpp"
#include "oatpp/network/tcp/server/ConnectionProvider.hpp"

#include "opentelemetry/exporters/ostream/span_exporter_factory.h"
#include "opentelemetry/sdk/trace/exporter.h"
#include "opentelemetry/sdk/trace/processor.h"
#include "opentelemetry/sdk/trace/simple_processor_factory.h"
#include "opentelemetry/sdk/trace/tracer_provider_factory.h"
#include "opentelemetry/trace/provider.h"

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
namespace trace_api = opentelemetry::trace;
namespace trace_sdk = opentelemetry::sdk::trace;
namespace trace_exporter = opentelemetry::exporter::trace;

namespace {
  void InitTracer() {
    auto exporter  = trace_exporter::OStreamSpanExporterFactory::Create();
    auto processor = trace_sdk::SimpleSpanProcessorFactory::Create(std::move(exporter));
    std::shared_ptr<opentelemetry::trace::TracerProvider> provider =
      trace_sdk::TracerProviderFactory::Create(std::move(processor));
    //set the global trace provider
    trace_api::Provider::SetTracerProvider(provider);
  }
  void CleanupTracer() {
    std::shared_ptr<opentelemetry::trace::TracerProvider> none;
    trace_api::Provider::SetTracerProvider(none);
  }

}

class Handler : public oatpp::web::server::HttpRequestHandler {
public:
  shared_ptr<OutgoingResponse> handle(const shared_ptr<IncomingRequest>& request) override {
    auto tracer = opentelemetry::trace::Provider::GetTracerProvider()->GetTracer("my-app-tracer");
    auto span = tracer->StartSpan("RollDiceServer");
    int low = 1;
    int high = 7;
    int random = rand() % (high - low) + low;
    // Convert a std::string to oatpp::String
    const string response = to_string(random);
    span->End();
    return ResponseFactory::createResponse(Status::CODE_200, response.c_str());
  }
};

void run() {
  auto router = oatpp::web::server::HttpRouter::createShared();
  router->route("GET", "/rolldice", std::make_shared<Handler>());
  auto connectionHandler = oatpp::web::server::HttpConnectionHandler::createShared(router);
  auto connectionProvider = oatpp::network::tcp::server::ConnectionProvider::createShared({"10.132.232.219", 80, oatpp::network::Address::IP_4});
  oatpp::network::Server server(connectionProvider, connectionHandler);
  OATPP_LOGI("Dice Server", "Server running on port %s", connectionProvider->getProperty("port").getData());
  server.run();
}

int main() {
  oatpp::base::Environment::init();
  InitTracer();
  srand((int)time(0));
  run();
  oatpp::base::Environment::destroy();
  CleanupTracer();
  return 0;
}
```

This is the same roll dice application taken it from the below link

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/cpp/getting-started/

But the roll dice code is not working.

Any help would appreciated.

Thanks
Maiya

download the application from

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/cpp/getting-started/

the above link and tried, but then compilation error while linking with specified libraries.